# Add and remove users from array list at runtime and keep the items details

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator, android-linearlayout

I have a game I am developing a game and before the game starts there is an option to add or remove player profiles from the game.
The idea is that the app owner can add or remove player profiles to the game so they can play solo or with friends on the sames device.

This is the main screen for this activity:

[image]

As you can see its quite self explainatry, all saved users are loaded and before the game starts at least one player must be selected to play the game using the add or remove buttons.

As mentioned earlier this functionality works fine if there is only one profile saved to the device.

[image]

After the user touches the add button that player then moves to the users player section and the details are stored in the active players array.

The problem I am having is when you have more than one player saved in the database. When you try the same function again only the second player is added. Like so:

[image]

No matter which user is added only the last user seems to be moved across. This is probably something really simple that I've missed but I have been stuck here for a while.

Display Users Function:

```
final HashMap<String,String> users = db.getUsers();
        if(users.size() > 0){
            noSavedPlayers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
        int userCount = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            final String id = pair.getKey().toString();
            final String username = pair.getValue().toString();
            //add this view to settings
            usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, allUsers, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                    AddRemoveUser(username,id,add,thisPlayer);
                }
            });
            userCount++;
            it.remove();
        }

private void AddRemoveUser(final String username, final String id, Boolean add, View thisPlayer){
        Log.d("USERNAME",username + " is");
        Boolean isAdded;
        if(activePlayers.size() == 0){
            isAdded = false;
        } else {
            isAdded = activePlayers.contains(username);
        }
        if(add){
            //check if player is allready add to the game
            if(!isAdded){
                //add this user to the game
                //remove form all players list
                activePlayers.add(username);
                activeIDs.add(id);
                allUsers.removeView(thisPlayer);
                usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, activeLayout, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                        if(add){
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,true,thisPlayer);
                        } else {
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,false,thisPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if(isAdded){
                //remove this user to the game
                //add back to all players list
                int current = activePlayers.indexOf(username);
                activePlayers.remove(current);
                activeIDs.remove(current);
                activeLayout.removeView(thisPlayer);
                usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, allUsers, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                        if(add){
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,true,thisPlayer);
                        } else {
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,false,thisPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        Log.d("VIEW",activePlayers.size() + "");
        noActivePlayers.setVisibility((activePlayers.size() > 0)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        noSavedPlayers.setVisibility((allUsers.getChildCount() > 0) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

usersClass.addToGameList function:

```
public void addToGameList(final Context context, final LinearLayout view, final String UserName, final String id, AddUserCallback callback){
        delegate = callback;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View user = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_add, null);

        //set data
        final TextView username = (TextView) user.findViewById(R.id.username);
        username.setText(UserName);
        Button save = (Button) user.findViewById(R.id.saveChanges);
        final Button delete = (Button) user.findViewById(R.id.deleteUserBtn);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("GAME","User is to be removed from this game.");
                delegate.addUser(false, user);
            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("GAME","User to be added to the game");
                delegate.addUser(true, user);
            }
        });
        view.addView(user);

    }
```

Full Activity:

```
package r1d.org.uk.oiaskatedice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import LocalDatabase.DatabaseHandler;

/**
 * Created by paul on 21/09/2015.
 */
public class PlayerSelect extends Activity {
    private ProFeatures PF;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private int maxPlayers = 3;
    private LinearLayout activeLayout;
    private LinearLayout allUsers;
    private TextView noActivePlayers;
    private TextView noSavedPlayers;
    private ArrayList<String> activeIDs;
    private ArrayList<String> activePlayers;
    private Users usersClass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_select);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        PF = new ProFeatures(this);
        activeIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        activePlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        activeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activePlayers);
        allUsers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.allPlayers);

        noActivePlayers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noActivePlayers);
        noSavedPlayers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noSavedPlayers);

        PF.checkForPro(new IsPro() {
            @Override
            public void isPro(Boolean isPro) {
                if(!isPro){
                    new AdManager(PlayerSelect.this);
                } else {
                    maxPlayers = 20;
                }
            }
        });
        //get tricks
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras.getString("Tricks")instanceof String){
            final String usedTricks = extras.getString("Tricks");
        } else {
            final String[] usedTricks = extras.getStringArray("Tricks");
        }
        //show active players
        //show all players
        usersClass = new Users();
        final HashMap<String,String> users = db.getUsers();
        if(users.size() > 0){
            noSavedPlayers.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
        int userCount = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            final String id = pair.getKey().toString();
            final String username = pair.getValue().toString();
            //add this view to settings
            usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, allUsers, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                    AddRemoveUser(username,id,add,thisPlayer);
                }
            });
            userCount++;
            it.remove();
        }
        //add more players
        //check for upgrade
        //gibe option to upgrage if needed
        //save all players to an array
        //save changes to saved player names
        //start game when all players are added

    }
    private void AddRemoveUser(final String username, final String id, Boolean add, View thisPlayer){
        Log.d("USERNAME",username + " is");
        Boolean isAdded;
        if(activePlayers.size() == 0){
            isAdded = false;
        } else {
            isAdded = activePlayers.contains(username);
        }
        if(add){
            //check if player is allready add to the game
            if(!isAdded){
                //add this user to the game
                //remove form all players list
                activePlayers.add(username);
                activeIDs.add(id);
                allUsers.removeView(thisPlayer);
                usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, activeLayout, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                        if(add){
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,true,thisPlayer);
                        } else {
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,false,thisPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if(isAdded){
                //remove this user to the game
                //add back to all players list
                int current = activePlayers.indexOf(username);
                activePlayers.remove(current);
                activeIDs.remove(current);
                activeLayout.removeView(thisPlayer);
                usersClass.addToGameList(PlayerSelect.this, allUsers, username, id, new AddUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void addUser(Boolean add, View thisPlayer) {
                        if(add){
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,true,thisPlayer);
                        } else {
                            AddRemoveUser(username,id,false,thisPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        Log.d("VIEW",activePlayers.size() + "");
        noActivePlayers.setVisibility((activePlayers.size() > 0)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        noSavedPlayers.setVisibility((allUsers.getChildCount() > 0) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Any help on this problem would be great, I also applogise for the question title as I don't really know where this problem would come under.

Comment: I think you'd be better served to have separate methods : addUser and removeUser. If nothing else it'd be easier to debug problems and it's best for one method to have a single responsibility.

Comment: It makes sense to split the separate the add and remove function but surely this would make no difference to the end outcome

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I did this and it worked fine, took a bit of working out but the code is cleaner now as well. You should post that as an answer

Comment: I added it. Glad the suggestion helped you towards a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know separating your methods into single responsibilities will not fix the problem directly, it would make it easier to read and debug because you can isolate the removal and addition of a user.

Most likely how the problem came about was doing too much which adds additional conditions and complicated logic in your code that could be avoided.

I would start by refactoring `AddRemoveUser(...)` to two methods which only do one thing: `addUser(...)` and `removeUser(...)`. Just doing that *may* fix the problem because you'll be simplifying the code and removing conditional checks and things which will be unnecessary in the new methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `break;` to stop the execution after  `AddRemoveUser(username,id,add,thisPlayer);`.  So that whenever the user is added/removed it will stop iterating. Anyways you are going to add/remove single user at a time.

Comment: I tried adding the break; this just kills the Iterator and only adds the first user from the database